# ASP.NET Core Kestrel throw exception when using Azure Key Vault (AKV) for Secrets Store CSI Driver in Azure Kuberenetes Service (AKS)

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I mount Azure Key Vault(AKV) certifcates to pods in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

[Use the Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver in an AKS cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver)

My pod's container image is based on `ASP.NET Core Web API` project template with below `appsettings.json`. I am trying to apply TLS on my service with `Kestrel`.

#### appsettings.json

[image: appsettings.json]

[Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration-1)

However I am getting below error message, even Azure Key Vault provides the certifcate with private key.

What am I missing here?

#### Error message

[image: ErrorMessage]

#### secret-provider-class.yml

[image: SecretProviderClass]

#### deployment.yml

[image: Deployment]

#### Busybox

I checked `PRIVATE KEY` exists with busybox pod.

[image: Busybox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check if the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698862/how-do-i-use-the-private-key-from-a-pfx-certificate-stored-in-azure-key-vault-in)  is the same case for you.
2. You may have to configure your  your data protection policy to use
   CryptographicAlogrithms as follow:

   ```
   .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                   {
                       EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                       ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
                   });
   ```

   Try configure the system with [ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.azuredataprotectionbuilderextensions.protectkeyswithazurekeyvault) in
   the Startup class.

   ```
   services.AddDataProtection()
           .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(kvClient, settings.KeyVaultKeyId);
   ```

   > Please note that When a Key Vault certificate is created, it can be
   > retrieved from the addressable secret with the private key in either
   > PFX or PEM format. The policy used to create the certificate must
   > indicate that the key is exportable. ***If the policy indicates
   > non-exportable, then the private key isn't a part of the value when
   > retrieved as a secret.***

**References:**

1. [Configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#protectkeyswithazurekeyvault-1)
2. [linux - No XML encryptor configured -Stack
   Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59331645/no-xml-encryptor-configured-when-using-key-vault) **/** [Using Azure Key Vault and Azure Storage to store Data
   Protection keys with ASP.NET Core - Joonas W's blog](https://joonasw.net/view/using-azure-key-vault-and-azure-storage-for-asp-net-core-data-protection-keys)